# Chicken for python: Extending python with the use of a shared library

Tags: python, scheme, shared-libraries, extend, chicken-scheme

I have read that it is possible to extend Python by writing a *shared library* that the Python interpreter can load as part of an import statement.

Could anyone point me to a simple example or tutorial where such an endeavour is accomplished by the use of *Chicken Scheme* instead of *C/C++*? Chicken is said to produce "portable and efficient C" - hence it should be suitable for such a task, no?

Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps you can use http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Extensions#find-header to load the Python.h headers needed in standard c/c++ development of a python extension?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I send an email to the chicken-users mailing list, pointing to this thread. Let us see what comes out if it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question. What you are suggesting looks like a good idea, however I don't think anyone has attempted it before and got round to writing a tutorial. There is an interface to call python from chicken scheme, see [pyffi](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/pyffi), this looks like a wrapper round the python C interface. Pyffi doesn't allow calls to be made in the other direction as asked in the question.

Creating a module for python in C involves using quite a lot of python API to manipulate python objects, because python is dynamically typed all parameters based into the C code are of type `PyObject` this goes for built in types, user defined types and collections. The C API then provides functions to manipulate these objects, perform arithmetic, add them to and from collections, etc. In addition manual reference counting must be carried out on all `pyObject`s, to ensure garbage collection can be carried out correctly in python. Documentation for this can be seen [here](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

It is possible to convert a `PyObject` into a C types such as int, double, etc, within the C code, which can make writing the module easier, if a function is large, or native C collections are being used. Then  the output must be wrapped back into `PyObject`s to return data back to python code.

Creating python modules in chicken could be much easier than C, as both are dynamically typed languages, removing the need of explicitly manipulating `PyObjects`, with the additional benefit of creating efficient C code. It looks like pyffi has gone some way towards mapping the types, although further work would be required to allow this to write modules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for elaborating the problems connected to linking C code with Python. I would give a an upvote for your answer, but I lack the reputation to do so for now.

Comment: There are other solutions such as cython, although this doesn't use scheme.